# Summation Problem

Tags: summation

[image]

It is given in the question that d|k means d is a positive of k. But, what does that mean?
Please just give an answer for this because rest I have to try it out myself.

Comment: It's missing a word. Positive "divisor" of $k$. It means $k$ is divisible by $d$, and $d$ is positive.

Comment: For example, the sum of the positive divisors of  $12$ is $1+2+3+4+6+12$.

Comment: m<n but the sum of positive divisors of m and n are equal. This implies that m has larger divisors(in terms of value). The values of d for m would be greater than that for n. Thus, 1/d for m would be less than that for n. Thus I choose option (A). Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is not correct.  For each divisor $d$ of $m$, $\frac md$ is also a divisor, so $$\sum_{d|m}\frac md=m\sum_{d|m}\frac 1d=\sum_{d|m}d\\\sum_{d|m}\frac 1d=\frac 1m\sum_{d|m}d\\\sum_{d|n}\frac 1d=\frac 1n\sum_{d|n}d\lt \frac 1m\sum_{m|d}d=\sum_{d|m}\frac 1d$$